# How to get flex-grow to work with *ngFor in Angular 10

Tags: css, angular, flexbox

I have a list of images that I want to display justified by width.

When I add a hardcoded list of images everything looks great, and the images cover the whole width of the container (see styles and code below):

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1800/1600" class="flex-item" [style.flex]="getFlexStyle(0)"/>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/180/180" class="flex-item" [style.flex]="getFlexStyle(1)"/>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/1202/722" class="flex-item" [style.flex]="getFlexStyle(2)"/>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/701/351" class="flex-item" [style.flex]="getFlexStyle(3)"/>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/602/822" class="flex-item" [style.flex]="getFlexStyle(4)"/>
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/700/1400" class="flex-item" [style.flex]="getFlexStyle(5)"/>
</div>
```

[image]

But when adding the same images using *ngFor, flex-grow is ignored:

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div *ngFor="let item of testFlexItems; let i = index">
        <img [src]="item" class="flex-item" [style.flex]="getFlexStyle(i)"/>
    </div>
</div>

testFlexItems=[
'https://picsum.photos/1800/1600',
'https://picsum.photos/180/180',
'https://picsum.photos/1202/722',
'https://picsum.photos/701/351',
'https://picsum.photos/602/822',
'https://picsum.photos/700/1400' ];
```

[image]

In both cases I use the same styles:

```
.flex-container {
width:100%;
background-color: black;
display: flex;
flex-flow: row wrap; 
place-content:stretch stretch; 
gap: 10px;
cursor:pointer;}

.flex-item {
height:150px;
max-width: 100%;
object-fit: cover;}
```

And a helper function (just to give different value flex-grow to each image):

```
flexValueArray=[4, 2, 5, 7, 3, 2, 6, 4, 3, 2];
getFlexStyle(index) {
let currentIndex = index % 10; //get the unity digit of the index e.g. index = 53 -> currentIndex = 3
let flexGrowValue = this.flexValueArray[currentIndex];
return `${flexGrowValue} 1`;  }
```

It seems flex is not able to calculate the remaining width when adding items in each row using  *ngFor, but does know it when all the images are given in advance.
I tried looking for a way to tell flex to "re-render" after all the items have loaded but didn't find any way to do this.

Comment: Have you tried putting the `*ngFor` on the `img` tag rather than on a surrounding `div`?

Comment: @R.Richards It actually does work that way! However it doesn't really help me because the 'img' tag is just a placeholder for the sake of the example. The actual code is more complex containing an 'a' tag containing an 'img'...

Comment: Can you use `(click)` on the image rather than an anchor tag? Then do any navigation in the typescript code.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it!

@R. Richards' suggestion actually solved the original question but the `img` tag was really just a place holder for my real requirement of an `img` inside an `a`.

I'm giving 2 solutions here:

Solution 1: A fix to the original code in the question is to simply add `fxFlex` to each `img` tag like so:

```
<div class="flex-container"><div *ngFor="let item of testFlexItems; let i = index">
    <img [src]="item" class="flex-item" [style.flex]="getFlexStyle(i)" fxFlex/> \\<-- add the fxFlex here
</div>
```

Solution 2: I managed to get it to work with `img` inside `a` elements like so:

Note that both HTML and CSS have changed from the original question.

```
.flex-container {
    width:100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap; 
    gap: 10px;
    cursor:pointer;}

.flex-item {
    height:200px;
    width: 100%;
    object-fit: cover;
}

<div class="flex-container">
  <div *ngFor="let item of testFlexItems; let i = index" [style.flex]="getFlexStyle(i)" fxFlex>
    <a [attr.href]="item">
       <img [src]="item" class="flex-item"/>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```